# Error raised Debug Assertion Failed _BLOCK_TYPE_IS_VALID when delete is used

Tags: c++, new-operator, assertions, delete-operator

I am trying a simple code in C++ but I am getting `Debug Assertion Failed _BLOCK_TYPE_IS_VALID` error when I delete the pointer. I don't know what I am making wrong. here is my code.

```
hash_map<string,string> m_hashDetails;
    m_hashDetails.insert(hash_map<string,string>::value_type("test",*(new string("test123"))));


    hash_map<string,string>::iterator myIterator;
    myIterator = m_hashDetails.find("test");
    if(myIterator == m_hashDetails.end())
    {
        printf("not found");
    }
    else
    {
        printf(myIterator->second.c_str());
        //this is where I get Debug Assertion Failed _BLOCK_TYPE_IS_VALID
        delete &(myIterator->second);
    }
```

When i delete the `second` field of `hash_map` I get `Debug Assertion Failed _BLOCK_TYPE_IS_VALID` error. What I am making wrong? I have allocated the `second` field using `new` operator? One thing I have noticed that if I change the hash_map definition to
`hash_map<string,string *> m_hashDetails;` and insert values like

```
m_hashDetails.insert(hash_map<string,string>::value_type("test",new string("test123")));
```

then `delete` doesn't give the error.. and works fine? What is actual reason of this error?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have allocated using `operator new`; BUT you are not storing the pointer to it. Rather you are storing of the allocated chunk;

```
int *p = new int(1); // ok, can be deleted later
int i = *new int(1); // memory leaked already, cannot delete as pointer is missed
```

Also, `std::string` is not a pointer type, so you cannot `delete` it.

So in your case, change the following line,

```
*(new string("test123"))
```

to

```
string("test123")
```

Then you don't have to `delete` it, as `std::string` is released automatically on the object destruction.